# Apple's SwiftUI tutorial produces a compilation error

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm just starting to learn SwiftUI, so I decided to work thru Apple's tutorial, using the latest Xcode (12.5). One line of code immediately got me a semantic error: `"Value of type 'Color' has no member 'accessibleFontColor'"`
Here's the entire source module:

```
//
//  CardView.swift
//  Scrumdinger
//
//  Created by Vacuumhead on 6/4/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(scrum.title).font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
                    .accessibilityElement(children: .ignore)
                    .accessibilityLabel(Text("Attendees"))
                    .accessibilityValue(Text("\(scrum.attendees.count)"))
                Spacer()
                Label("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes)", systemImage: "clock")
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                    .accessibilityElement(children: .ignore)
                    .accessibilityLabel(Text("Meeting length"))
                    .accessibilityValue(Text("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes) minutes"))
            }
            .font(.caption)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.color.accessibleFontColor)

    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.data[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.color)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

The line that gets the error is the last line of `body`:

```
.foregroundColor(scrum.color.accessibleFontColor)
```

The message is `"Value of type 'Color' has no member 'accessibleFontColor'"`.
The program compiles and runs just fine when I comment out that line, of course without any color. I've been writing C++ since the age of dinosaurs but I'm new to SwiftUI and don't even know where I should look to fix this.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How scrum model looks like? Can you show?

Comment: Swift isn't so different from other languages in this respect. If the compiler can't find a definition for a symbol you're using, whether it's the name of a class, struct, variable, enum, protocol, etc., it's going to complain until you resolve it. So the two places you'd want to look for this error are 1) in your project, to see if the thing you're using is there at all; and 2) at the example code/project/text, to see if it's defined there somewhere and you missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a file that you're probably missing in the sample project called `Color+Codable.swift` that defines some extensions on `Color`. One is `accessibleFontColor`:

```
extension Color {
  var accesibleFontColor : Color {
    //etc.
  }
}
```

Download the files from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/managing-state-and-life-cycle and make sure that you're using `Color+Codable.swift` in your project.